# Lattice Diagrams with Tikz-CD

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm writing a code with Tikz-cd. I want to make a lattice diagram such that  I want to connect a label in the third row with a label in the first row. Here's the code and the output:

```
\documentclass[11pt,amssymb]{amsart}



\usepackage{sansmathaccent} 
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule 
in tables
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}


The following diagram gives the lattice diagram of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em,row sep=1.5em]
& \langle 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{12} \\
&& \langle 2 \rangle \arrow[ul] \\
\langle 3 \rangle \arrow[urr] 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I want to be able to connect `$\langle 3 \rangle 1$` directly with the label `$\mathbb{Z}_{12}$`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `\arrow[uur] ` (2 `up` and 1 `right`).

Comment: @Sigur Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

To direct the arrow up two rows and right one column, use `\arrow[uur]`.

[image]

Similarly, `\arrow[uuurr]` will direct the arrow up 3 rows and right 2 columns, as in the arrow from `<6>` to `<2>`.

I changed the `row sep` and `column sep` values since I thought the diagram looked better if it was a bit wider relative to its height. That is just my opinion. However, it is good practice not to use `em` units for vertical spacing. If you want vertical spacing that adjusts to font size changes, use `ex` units instead. `1em` is approximately the width of a capital `M` in the current font, whereas `1ex` is approximately the height of a lower-case `x`. I changed both units to `cm`, which will not be affected by font size.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

The following diagram gives the lattice diagram of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1cm,row sep=.3cm]
& \langle 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{12} \\
&& \langle 2 \rangle \arrow[ul] \\
\langle 3 \rangle \arrow[uur] \\
&& \langle 4 \rangle \arrow[uu] \\
\langle 6 \rangle \arrow[uu] \arrow[uuurr] \\
& \langle 0 \rangle \arrow[ul] \arrow[uur]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,amssymb]{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}

The following diagram gives the lattice diagram of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
  & \langle 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{12} &  \\
 &  & \langle 2 \rangle \arrow[lu] \\
\langle 3 \rangle \arrow[rru] \arrow[ruu] &  & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```